# Add marker on map with label in Xamarin Android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm creating a Xamarin Android App in Visual Studio.

I've added a Google map v2 to my app, and also added markers. On tap of these markers, I've opened an info window.

Now, I want to customize these markers, so that markers are displayed with label on the top of it, like below:

[image]

Please suggest with code, for how to do this in Xamarin. I'm new to this environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) as binding-library.

Sample app is here - [oystehei/MapsUtilityDemo: Demo project for Google Maps Utility bindings project in Xamarin](https://github.com/oystehei/MapsUtilityDemo).

How to add a "text on marker" is described as follows.

```
var iconGen = new IconGenerator(activity);

var markerOp = new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(latLng);

iconGen.SetStyle(IconGenerator.StyleOrange);
markerOp.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBitmap(
    iconGen.MakeIcon("text_on_marker")));

gogleMap.AddMarker(markerOp);
```